# Python string split on possible None value

Tags: python, django, string, split, nonetype

I'm building a json and I want to split a comma seperated list ID's in array of ID's and put in the json. The problem is that the list can also be NULL in the database, thus None in python

part of the code looks like:

```
'followupsteps': [{
    'id': stepid,
} for stepid in string.split(step.followupsteps, ',')
```

I tried things like:

```
'followupsteps': [{
    'id': stepid,
} for stepid in (string.split(step.followupsteps, ',') if not None else [])]
```

and

```
'followupsteps': [{
    'id': stepid,
} for stepid in string.split((step.followupsteps if not None else ''), ',')]
```

they all result in the Django/python  error:
Exception Value:
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

any ideas?

Comment: Is there any way you can check whether the variable is `None` before the loop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to test if `step.followupsteps` is boolean true instead:

```
'followupsteps': [] if not step.followupsteps else [{
    'id': stepid,
} for stepid in step.followupsteps.split(',')]
```

You are instead testing if `not None` is True,  which it just so happens to be:

```
>>> bool(not None)
True
```

`not step.followupsteps` is going to be True if it is an empty string, `None`, numeric 0 or an empty container. You could also use `if step.followupsteps is None` but why limit yourself.

Another way of spelling this:

```
'followupsteps': [{
    'id': stepid,
} for stepid in (step.followupsteps.split(',') if step.followupsteps else [])]
```

but by just returning an empty list first you avoid the empty list comprehension altogether.

Comment: @JonClements: that returns a list with one empty string in it. You end up with `[{'id': ''}]` instead of `[]`.

Answer (score 2):

Your ternary statement expands to:

```
if not None:
   step.followupsteps
else:
   ''
```

`not None` always evaluates to `True`, so this is equivalent to not writing an `if/else` statement at all.

You want to be writing `(thing to evaluate) if step.followupsteps else (default thing)`, taking advantage of the 'falsiness' of an object that is `None`.  Or, if it's more convenient, `(default thing) if not step.followupsteps else (thing to evaluate)`.